# downloading .apk turns into .txt on phone

Tags: android, html, download

I have two apks on my [website](http://origamiapp.blogspot.com/p/downloads.html).  I can click the link and download them to my computer and it works fine.  When I download them on my phone, the first one works fine, but the second downloads as a .txt instead of an .apk.  I can go on my phone and rename the file as an apk and then it works fine.  But why is it showing up as .txt and how do I make it stop?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

While I am unable to account for the fact that the problem occurs on only one file out of the two, examining the headers sent by mediafire.com indicate that the file is sent with a content type of **text/plain**. It is possible that the android browsers sees this header and adds a .txt extension. Since this is outside your control, your best bet would be to host the files on your own server and add a mime-type of **application/vnd.android.package-archive** for the .apk extension.

Comment: Ok, I think I have it fixed now, I have it hosted somewhere else now and it works, so it must be related to that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the plus sign (+) from the filename and see if it makes a difference.